# Need to identify duplicate values in sheets and tag as duplicate or not based on value + date

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a table that stores client service records by date and Client ID. I need to be able to identify whether the client received a service previous to the most recent date and, if there was at least one service prior to the quarter in which the current service takes place, tag the client in the current service record as having been "previously served".

I used `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:D2, A2, $A$2:D2, "<>")>1, "Previously Served","New")` to tag a client as having been previously served at any time, but the problem is that it tags a client whose services occurred within the same quarter as having been "previously served", and I can't figure out how to limit the result to only services provided in a previous quarter. Table entries are stored by date and not sorted.

Comment: Can you share a sheet in the question?

Comment: It's a spreadsheet I use for work so I don't feel comfortable sharing. I think I may have worked it out using the Query function to show the number of services provided in a quarter, and then using IF formulas to tag as previously served, but I know there must be a much more elegant way to accomplish this.

Comment: You could make a new one and share that.